# Ajax loop json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have such results and I need to append them in my view:

```
val: {email: Array(1), first_name: Array(1)}
    email: Array(1)
        0: "The email field is required."
        length: 1
        __proto__: Array(0)
    first_name: Array(1)
        0: "The first name field is required."
        length: 1
        __proto__: Array(0)
        __proto__: Object
```

## code

```
$('#submitRegister').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
    });

    var formData = {};
    $('#registerForm').find("input[name]").each(function (index, node) {
        formData[node.name] = node.value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '{{route('frontend.register.validate')}}',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            formData,
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
            $(data.errors).each(function (index, value) {
                console.log('val: ', value);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

`html`

```
<div id="errors"></div>
```

**any idea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) then check and loop inside each array

```js
val  = {email: ["The email field is required."], first_name: ["The first name field is required."] };


var errs = []

keys = Object.keys(val)

for(var i=0; i<keys.length;i++)
{
 
  if(Array.isArray(val[keys[i]]))
  {
    for(var j=0; j<val[keys[i]].length; j++)
      errs.push(val[keys[i]][j])
  }
  else
      errs.push(val[i])
}

var str = '';
$.each(errs, function( index, value ) {
  str += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
});

$('#msgs').html(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="msgs"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementById()` to find the element you want to append things to, then you can use document.createElement() to create an element to append, and then you can use `append()` to append it to the div. So, all together:

```
var errors = document.getElementById('errors'); // Getting the div we want to append to
var newElement = document.createElement('h1'); // Creating the element we want to append to the errors div
newElement.textContent = value; // Setting the text value of the new element to the information we want to display
errors.append(newElement); // Appending the new element to the errors div
```

You should be able to put this in your .each() function, after the console.log().

Comment: returns `[object Object]`

Comment: Do you want to add an element to your page that has the value of the object? Can you please provide some more context to the object, and what you want to do with it. Are you trying to display a value of the object in a new element on the page?

Comment: no, all i need to return is list of `The email field is required.` and `The first name field is required.`

Comment: Like this : `<ul><li>The email field is required.</li><li>The first name field is required.</li></ul>`

Comment: If you can get the object's value as `<ul><li>The email field is required.</li><li>The first name field is required.</li></ul>` you could do `var errors = document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML = value;` This should insert the html into the div on the page.

Comment: still getting object object (maybe i did it wrong, would you mind update your answer?)

Comment: What is the value of the data variable returned by the AJAX call? I suspect the way you are handling the data might be where the issue is.